# Changing the background on a table?

Tags: html, css

As you can tell by the script below, I have a problem, I'm not going to go into much detail as to what the script does, because it is pretty obvious based on just reading the script...

```
<body background="Background here" bgproperties="fixed">
<?php
$DBNAME="login info here";
$DBUSER="login info here";
$DBPASSWORD="login info here";
$DBHOST="login info here";

//Connection is below
mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD) or die("<center>Cannot connect to MySQL</center>");
mysql_select_db($DBNAME) or die("<center>Cannot Connect to MYSQL</center>");

$sql = 'SELECT `nick`, `votes` FROM `votesdb` ORDER BY `votes` desc LIMIT 0, 10 '; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "{$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='0' bgcolor=#FFFFFF><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

As you can tell by going here: [http://legacyserver.info/fbxtop.php][1]
The tables background does not blend with the image,tiling background on the rest of the page, obviously, this looks ugly and weird, How could I change the background of the table to the background of the rest of the page! I tried googling, but had no avail. Please help! :)

Obviously I also need to figure out how to change the text color too :)

Comment: valid html is the starting point: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Flegacyserver.info%2Ffbxtop.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this :

```
<table border='0' style='background-color: transparent; color: white;'>
```

If you want to show table at the center of the page you can add margin:

```
<table border='0' style='background-color: transparent; color: white;margin:0 auto;'>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! you helped a bunch! Thank you for not only telling me what I needed, but giving me the option of making it look even better :)

Answer (score 1):

On the table add the following style or give it a class name with the following style :

```
background-color: transparent;
```

You will just have to change the font color for the table as well.

Comment: But how do I change the font color? Sorry, I'm a bit new to getting data from mysql.

Comment: Check Virtual's response below. Sorry, I assumed you know how to add inline styles to elements. Virtual gives you an excellent example on how to add them. Shout if you need more help!

Answer (score 1):

Add the style attribute to table and set it to 'background-color: transparent;color: white;'

like,

```
echo "<table border='0' style='background-color: transparent; color: white;'><tr>";
```